# Testing angular component which contains a custom form control?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have a simple angular component like below.

```
import { Component, Input, forwardRef, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from "@angular/forms";

export const CUSTOM_CHECKBOX_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckBoxComponent),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
    selector: "checkbox",
    templateUrl: "./checkBox.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./checkBox.component.scss"],
    providers: [CUSTOM_CHECKBOX_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class CheckBoxComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input() name: string;
    // Placeholders for the callbacks which are later provided
    // by the Control Value Accessor
    private innerValue: any = "";
    private onTouchedCallback: () => void = () => { };
    private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = () => { };

    // get and set accessor----------------------
    get value(): any {
        return this.innerValue;
    }
    set value(v: any) {
        if (v !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = v;
            this.onChangeCallback(v);
        }
    }

    // From ControlValueAccessor interfaces--------------
    writeValue(value: any): void {
        if (value !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = value;
        }
    }
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void { this.onChangeCallback = fn; }
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void { this.onTouchedCallback = fn; }
}
```

I am writing a unit test for. My test is like below

```
    import { CheckBoxComponent, CUSTOM_CHECKBOX_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "./checkBox.component";
        import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, tick } from "@angular/core/testing";
        import { DebugElement, Component } from "@angular/core";
        import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";
        import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
        import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

        @Component({
            selector: "tac-checkbox",
            template: `<checkbox name="checkboxId1" label="Checkbox Label" [(ngModel)] = "checkValue" > `,
        })
        class CustomTestClass {
            checkValue = false;
        }

        describe("Component: CheckBoxComponent", () => {
            let component: CheckBoxComponent;
            let fixture: ComponentFixture<CheckBoxComponent>;
            let testComponent: CustomTestClass;
            let testFixture: ComponentFixture<CustomTestClass>;

            beforeEach(async(() => {
                TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                    imports: [FormsModule, CommonModule],
                    declarations: [CheckBoxComponent, CustomTestClass],
                    providers: [CUSTOM_CHECKBOX_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
                }).compileComponents().then(() => {
                    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CheckBoxComponent);
                    component = fixture.componentInstance;
                    component.name = "checkbox";
                });
            }));

            it("...", fakeAsync(() => {
                testFixture = TestBed.createComponent(CustomTestClass);
                testComponent = testFixture.componentInstance;

                fixture.detectChanges();
                const onChangeEvent = (change: any) => { console.log("There were changes ", change); };
                const registerOnChangeMock = spyOn(component, "registerOnChange").and.callThrough();
                const registerOnTouchedMock = spyOn(component, "registerOnTouched").and.callThrough();
                const onMockWriteValue = spyOn(component, "writeValue").and.callThrough();

                component.registerOnChange(onChangeEvent);

                component.registerOnTouched(onChangeEvent);

                testComponent.checkValue = !testComponent.checkValue;
                fixture.detectChanges();
                testFixture.detectChanges();
                tick();
                fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
                    expect(registerOnChangeMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); //pass
                    expect(registerOnTouchedMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
 //pass
                    expect(onMockWriteValue).toHaveBeenCalled(); //failed
                    expect(testComponent.checkValue).toEqual(component.value); //failed
                });
            }));

        });
```

From my test above, i expect `component.value` to equal `testComponent.value`. This failed however, My question is considering i changed the testComponent value, shouldn't the control value be updated as well? Also i was expecting the `writeValue` to be called whenever i changed the testComponent value, however, it wasn't. Please what am i doing wrong ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the `component` is not same instance as you are expecting. In `beforeEach` you are creating new `CheckBoxComponent` and in `it` you are creating instance of your test host component `CustomTestClass`. Angular creates new `CheckBoxComponent` as a child of your test host component, so when you change the input value for the host component it is not reflected in `component` instance.

What should you do is to create just the test host component and in that component inject the `CheckBoxComponent` with `@ViewChild` and use that instance in tests.

Code:

remove `.then` part in `beforeEach`.

edit your test host component:

```
class CustomTestClass {
   checkValue = false;
   @ViewChild(CheckBoxComponent) checkBoxComponent: CheckBoxComponent;
}
```

replace `component` with `testComponent.checkBoxComponent` in your test.